# How do I display an array object with certain conditions in php?

Tags: php, html, loops

I want to make a selection display like the following in html:

```
<div name="option_a">
    <p>result for option_a</p>
    <img src="option_a_image"></img>
</div>
<div name="option_b">
    <p>result for option_b</p>
    <img src="option_b_image"></img>
</div>
<div name="option_c">
    <p>result for option_c</p>
    <img src="option_c_image"></img>
</div>
<div name="option_d">
    <p>result for option_d</p>
    <img src="option_d_image"></img>
</div>
```

using this array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [option_a] => its option a
            [option_a_image] => its an image for option a
            [option_b] => its option b
            [option_b_image] => its an image for option b
            [option_c] => its option c
            [option_c_image] => its an image for option c
            [option_d] => its option d
            [option_d_image] => its an image for option d
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [option_a] => its option a
            [option_a_image] => its an image for option a
            [option_b] => its option b
            [option_b_image] => its an image for option b
            [option_c] => its option c
            [option_c_image] => its an image for option c
            [option_d] => its option d
            [option_d_image] => its an image for option d
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [option_a] => its option a
            [option_a_image] => its an image for option a
            [option_b] => its option b
            [option_b_image] => its an image for option b
            [option_c] => its option c
            [option_c_image] => its an image for option c
            [option_d] => its option d
            [option_d_image] => its an image for option d
    )
)
```

but I wanted to make it more concise using loops. I have tried the following:

```
<?php foreach($array[0] as $type=>$value ){
    if(strpos($type,'option_') !== false){ ?>           
    <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 98%; margin: auto">
    <div class="card-body">
                                            
    <label ><input type='radio' name='r1' tabindex='5'> <span><?php echo $value ?></span></label> <br>        
                                            
    </div>
    </div>
<?php } } ?>
```

but loops like this can't produce the view I want to create.
So how do I get the loop to form the result I want to produce?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work for you:

```php
$array[0] = [
    "option_a"       => "its option a",
    "option_a_image" => "its an image for option a",
    "option_b"       => "its option b",
    "option_b_image" => "its an image for option b",
    "option_c"       => "its option c",
    "option_c_image" => "its an image for option c",
    "option_d"       => "its option d",
    "option_d_image" => "its an image for option d"
];

$thisElementIsOption = true;
$option = [];

foreach($array[0] as $type => $value) {
    if(strpos($type, 'option_') !== false) {
        if ($thisElementIsOption) {
            $option['name'] = $type;
        } else {
            $option['image'] = $type;

            $name = $option['name'];
            $image = $option['image'];
            echo "<div name='$name'><p>result for $name</p><img src='$image'></img></div>".PHP_EOL;

            $option = [];
        }

        $thisElementIsOption = !$thisElementIsOption;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
<div name='option_a'><p>result for option_a</p><img src='option_a_image'></img></div>
<div name='option_b'><p>result for option_b</p><img src='option_b_image'></img></div>
<div name='option_c'><p>result for option_c</p><img src='option_c_image'></img></div>
<div name='option_d'><p>result for option_d</p><img src='option_d_image'></img></div>
```

In this solution I use `$thisElementIsOption` as a flag variable and make an array `$option` and make the html output decussate

Comment: what is the use of  $thisElementIsOption = !$thisElementIsOption; after if else ?

Comment: When I want to make an html like this `<div name='option_a'><p>result for option_a</p><img src='option_a_image'></img></div>` I need to iterate two rows , because i need the option data and option image data so I use this flag variable to do this

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. its very usefull